Datastore Query in AWS Amplify Returning Empty Array for Specific Field in React Native
I'm using Datastore from AWS Amplify for a react-native project. In all the other screens of this app, my queries have worked perfectly. However, when I wrote a query for this table asking for all entries that have the same 'userquizattemptstatisticsID' field, it always returns null even though when I check AWS Amplify studio, it shows entries with the same field.
When I changed the query for all entries with the same "id" field, it returned with the right entries. In the code below, the console.log just shows an empty array.
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserQuestions = async() => {
      const userQuestions = await DataStore.query(UserQuizQuestionStatistics, u =>
        u.userquizattemptstatisticsID.contains(attemptID)
      )
      setUserQuestions(userQuestions)
    }
    fetchUserQuestions().catch(error => {
      console.log("Failed to fetch UserModuleStatistics: ", error)
    })
    console.log("userQuestions:", userQuestions)

